# Text overflowing and cannot be controlled

Tags: flutter, dart

I've got an issue where text inside a Column inside a Row overflows the other things in the Row. This is what it looks like when the description is short.

[image: No overflow]

But if the description gets longer it overflows and hides the settings button:

[image: overflow]

I've tried using the overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis, and TextOverflow.clip properties in the Text widget, this does nothing.tried to change the Column and Row to Wrap widgets

```
child: Row(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          CircleAvatar(
                            backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                                userData.profilePic ?? kBackupProfilePic),
                            radius: 40.0,
                          ),
                          SizedBox(width: 20.0),
                          Column(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                              Text(
                                userData.name ?? "Cannot find name",
                                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 20.0,
                                ),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(height: 5.0),
                              Text(
                                userData.description ??
                                    "Cannot find description",
                                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                maxLines: 5,
                                style: TextStyle(),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          SizedBox(width: 40.0),
                          IconButton(
                            icon: Image.asset('assets/cogwheel.png'),
                            iconSize: 50,
                            onPressed: () {
                              openSettings();
                            },
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
```

I've tried placing the the Row in a Container with a Flexible, but that causes red screen Flutter error.

When I replace the Row and Columns with Wrap widgets I get:

[image: wrap]

```
child: Wrap(
                        direction: Axis.horizontal,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          CircleAvatar(
                            backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                                userData.profilePic ?? kBackupProfilePic),
                            radius: 40.0,
                          ),
                          SizedBox(width: 20.0),
                          Wrap(
                            direction: Axis.vertical,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                              Text(
                                userData.name ?? "Cannot find name",
                                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 20.0,
                                ),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(height: 5.0),
                              Text(
                                //"brobbi",
                                userData.description ??
                                    "Cannot find description",
                                overflow: TextOverflow.clip,
                                maxLines: 5,
                                style: TextStyle(),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          SizedBox(width: 40.0),
                          IconButton(
                            icon: Image.asset('assets/cogwheel.png'),
                            iconSize: 50,
                            onPressed: () {
                              PopupLayout(top: topMarginPopupLayout).showPopup(
                                  context, SettingsScreen(), 'Cibus Settings');
                            },
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
```

This cannot be too hard. I just want my text to linebreak or cut if it's so long that it'll cause overflows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `TextOverflow` to the framework should know where is the current widget's bounds are. Inside `Column` widget framework cant determine cross axis (horizontal) bounds.

To make ellipsis work you have to wrap that text widget inside an `Expanded` widget with a parent `Row`. or wrapping your `Column` inside `Expanded` would do fine.

```
Row(children:[
        //Circle Avatar here
        Expanded( // Wrap Expanded here
         child:Column(
           children: <Widget>[
             SizedBox(height: 20.0),
            Text(
              "Cannot find name",
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
            maxLines:1,
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 20.0,
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 5.0),
          Text(
             "Cannot find description",
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
            maxLines: 5,
            style: TextStyle(),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
      ])
```